# Adding columns between objects in R

Tags: r

file1:

```
pos qual    

15 bad    
1 good
18 bad
19 good
2 bad
3 bad
4 good
16 bad
17 ugly
```

file2:

```
start stop region
1 10 heaven
11 15 hell
16 20 seaLevel
```

How can I create this:

```
pos qual region    
1 good heaven
2 bad heaven
3 bad heaven
4 good heaven
15 bad hell
16 bad seaLevel
17 ugly seaLevel
18 bad seaLevel
19 good seaLevel
```

I have not used R for a while so its all gone! Frustrated for the time spent learning just to forget.

This comes to mind but something is missing and I weakly recall there is a shortcut available:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(file1...
    for j in 1:nrow(file2...
        if(file1[i]$pos>file2[j]$start & file1[i]$pos<file2[j]$stop){
            file1[i]$region=file2[j]$region
}
```

Comment: isn't `file1$region <- ifelse(file1[, 1] %in% 1:10, "heaven", "hell") ` enough?

Comment: This looks nice for this special demo. But not if there are more categories of regions like "heaven" "hell" "sea level".

Answer (score 0):

You could do a rolling join with data.table:

```
df1 <- read.table(text="pos qual    
1 good
2 bad
3 bad
4 good
15 bad
16 bad
17 ugly
18 bad
19 good", header=TRUE)

df2 <- read.table(text="start stop region
1 10 heaven
11 20 hell", header=TRUE)

library(data.table)
DT1 <- data.table(df1, key="pos")
DT2 <- data.table(df2, key="start")
DT2[DT1, roll=T]

#    start stop region qual
# 1:     1   10 heaven good
# 2:     2   10 heaven  bad
# 3:     3   10 heaven  bad
# 4:     4   10 heaven good
# 5:    15   20   hell  bad
# 6:    16   20   hell  bad
# 7:    17   20   hell ugly
# 8:    18   20   hell  bad
# 9:    19   20   hell good
```